# DropdownList For Single Attribute Like gender in form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

### Database object Properties for Gender Attribute

I have a Patient table and want to create drop down list for its field "Gender". The options should be either "Male" or "Female". How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The one simple way to create `dropdown list` with `MVC` is by using `enum`:

For exmaple,

Model:

```
 namespace demo.Models
 {
     public enum gender
     {
        Male,
        Female
     }
     //your model class instead of this
     public class MyModel
     {         
     }
```

}

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult BindGenderView()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BindGenderView(FormCollection fc)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('selected gender is :"+fc["gender"]+"') 
         </script>");
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@using demo.Models

<h2>BindGenderView</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("BindGenderView","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <p>Selcet Gender:</p>
    @Html.DropDownList("gender",new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(gender))),"-- 
    select--")
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />    
}
```

this sample code may help you